# C# multi-value cookies not working

Tags: c#, cookies

Hi I am creating a cookie in the following way:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieNameHere");
cookie.Values["test1"] = "Value1";
cookie.Values["test2"] = "Value2";
cookie.Values["test3"] = "Value3";
//I have also tried cookie.Values.Add("test1", "Value1");

cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365d);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie); //here I have also tried HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

but when I read out the cookie using the following code:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieNameHere");
cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CookieNameHere"];
```

I always get that the `cookie.Values` is empty

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Normally you would write the cookie in a `Response`, and then read it from subsequent `Requests`. I see you're trying to read it from the `Response` - is this within the context of the same HTTP request, or just a typo?

Comment: That was it @Ross, I was being stupid and trying to read them from the response! If you put this as the answer I will mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would write the cookie in a `Response`, and then read it from subsequent `Requests`.

I see you're trying to read it from the `Response` - is this within the context of the same HTTP request, or just a typo?

Try

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieNameHere"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask for those Cookies in a Request.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CookieName"];
```